# Write rows into new dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

New programmer with pandas here. I'm working on separating rows withing a pandas dataframe into new dataframes. I have a dataframe that looks something like this:

```
In [1]: print (df)

       first_name                    email      organization
0            Brad           brad@gmail.com              org1 
1           Jared          jared@gmail.com              org2 
2          Daniel         daniel@gmail.com              org3
3         Michael        michael@gmail.com              org1 
4           Jaime          jaime@gmail.com              org2
```

What I want to do is go through each row in the dataframe, identify which organization the row belongs to (eg. Brad belongs to org1, Daniel belongs to org3), and then I want to write that row into a new dataframe. In this case, I'd want to have 3 new dataframes, each of which would look like the following:

Org1:

```
In [3]: print (org1)

       first_name                    email      organization
0            Brad           brad@gmail.com              org1
1         Michael        michael@gmail.com              org1
```

Org2:

```
In [4]: print (org2)

       first_name                    email      organization
0           Jared          jared@gmail.com              org2 
1           Jaime          jaime@gmail.com              org2
```

Org3:

```
In [3]: print (org3)

       first_name                    email      organization
0          Daniel         daniel@gmail.com              org3
```

How would I create a loop that iterates through each row in my original dataframe, identify the dataframe to write to through the value in a specific column, and then actually writes it to the dataframe?

The first time that the loops encounters the value, I would want it to create a brand new dataframe. After that, any subsequent rows with the same value should get added to it-- not create a new one entirely. Any help (and wisdom for understanding how loops work in regards to dataframes) would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option 1**
`groupby`

```
orgs = []
for _, g in df.groupby('organisation', as_index=False):
    orgs.append(g)
```

Or,

```
orgs = [g for _, g in df.groupby('organization', as_index=False)]
```

Now, `orgs` is a list of dataframes, one for each org.

Alternatively, if you want the result as a `dict`, use -

```
orgs = {i : g for i, g in df.groupby('organization', as_index=False)}
```

Now, to access the dataframe for `org1`, call `orgs['org1']`.

---

**Option 2**
Another option would be filtering using `pd.Series.unique` -

```
orgs = []
for o in df.organization.unique():
    orgs.append(df.query('organization == @o'))
```

Or,

```
orgs = [df.query('organization == @o') for o in df.organization.unique()]
```

Or,

```
orgs = { o : df.query('organization == @o') for o in df.organization.unique()}
```